# Does dplyr or plyr have a remainder function?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Does dplyr or plyr have a remainder function?

Let say I have a series of MODE (1-25) to look into

for example dataset Main

```
idc3 = c("23|24")

column0|column1|column2|column3|MODE1|MODE2|MODE3
     4 |  83   |   23  |   863 | 85  | 86  |  45
    53 |  26   |   9   |   153 | 23  | 34  |  85
    33 |  66   |   91  |   693 | 95  | 23  |  74
     6 |  87   |   27  |   863 | 47  | 56  |  52
    57 |  27   |   9   |   153 | 78  | 38  |  64
    37 |  67   |   97  |   693 | 34  | 86  |  24

cut  <- Main[unique(grep(paste(idc3), Main$MODE1)), ]
cut2 <- Main[unique(grep(paste(idc3), Main$MODE2)), ]
cut3 <- Main[unique(grep(paste(idc3), Main$MODE3)), ]

  column0|column1|column2|column3|MODE1|MODE2|MODE3
      53 |  26   |   9   |  153  | 23  | 34  |  85
      33 |  66   |   91  |  693  | 95  | 23  |  74
      37 |  67   |   97  |  693  | 34  | 86  |  24
```

What if I would like the remainder dataset

```
column0|column1|column2|column3|MODE|MODE2|MODE3
     4 |  83   |   23  |   863 | 85 | 86  |  45        
     6 |  87   |   27  |   863 | 47 | 56  |  52
    57 |  27   |   9   |   153 | 78 | 38  |  64
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on how this is related to `dplyr`... Does your data have an `id` column? If you had some unique row identifier called `id` then your `remainder = Main[!Main$id %in% c(cut$id, cut2$id, cut3$id), ]`.

Comment: I believe a more appropriate way than regex would be `Reduce("|", lapply(Main[c("MODE1", "MODE2", "MODE3")], "%in%", c(23, 24)))` to check if every row has any "MODE_" column with either a 23 or 24. If you negate (`!`) this, you'll get your second desired result.

Comment: Thanks Alexis_laz i will try this

Comment: Thanks for the help Gregor

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating three separate cuts, you can create an index with one function call. You will then be able to choose the matched columns or opposite as needed:

```
idc3 = c(23,24)
indx <- as.logical(rowSums(sapply(df[,5:7], `%in%`, idc3)))
df[indx,]
#   column0 column1 column2 column3 MODE1 MODE2 MODE3
# 2      53      26       9     153    23    34    85
# 3      33      66      91     693    95    23    74
# 6      37      67      97     693    34    86    24
df[!indx,]
#   column0 column1 column2 column3 MODE1 MODE2 MODE3
# 1       4      83      23     863    85    86    45
# 4       6      87      27     863    47    56    52
# 5      57      27       9     153    78    38    64
```